# CUDA debugging with microsoft vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

When I debugging cuda(v 5.0) code:

[image]

For example add two vectors I can't see debugging details such as block idx,warp index

[image]

shown in [nvidia nsight site](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition)), i can see only locals, call stack,... that shown in c programs.

Comment: set a breakpoint and make a screenshot, show us what you see.

Comment: i uploud a video that show this problem: http://www.4shared.com/document/bP9pX2q5/CUDA.html  when i click start cuda debugging nothing happen and breakpoint not work!

Comment: unfortunately the video can be downloaded without registration.

Comment: i meant to write "can not be downloaded without registration"

Comment: i don't know problem? can you explain? register in 4shared site, then open that link, click download button, click free download, save this swf file and open with a browser (firefox, internet explorer,...)

Comment: the problem is that i do not wish to register on some sharing website.

Comment: use this link: http://www.herosh.com/download/11097535/CUDA.swf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have made a breakpoint in the host code but you have no breakpoint in the device code.
When debugging with the regular VS debugger, the debugger will hit breakpoints in the host code but not in the device code.
When debugging with the CUDA debugger, the debugger will hit breakpoints in the device code but not in the host code.